# Sorting an array by multiple properties including date

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to sort an array by an enumeration, then by a number then by date. When I do it with enumeration and number it seems to work fine however when I include the date at the end it messes everything.

Here's my code:

```
enum myType { 
  high,
  medium,
  low
}

myArray.sort((a, b) =>
  myType[a.type] - myType[b.type] ||
  a.classification - b.classification ||
  new Date(a.time) > new Date(b.time)
    ? -1
    : 1
);
```

However this seems to sort the opposite meaning it sorts by type in the opposite order where low first and high last. How do we go about this?

Update: Date will get passed as this: 2017-07-02T14:59:55.711Z

Comment: please add the style of the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the style of `time`, you need to wrap the ternary to prevent the reading of all expressions for the ternary.

```
myArray.sort((a, b) =>
    myType[a.type] - myType[b.type] ||
    a.classification - b.classification ||
    (new Date(a.time) > new Date(b.time)
        ? -1
        : 1)
);
```

By using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant strings, you could take a string comparison with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```
myArray.sort((a, b) =>
    myType[a.type] - myType[b.type] ||
    a.classification - b.classification ||
    a.time.localeCompare(b.time)
);
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.. but why did it work with the wrapping the ternary? I'd never figure it out myself

Comment: the parts before are parts of the ternary, not of the result.

Comment: Don't the > ? : have precedence over the || ?

Comment: no. please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

Comment: I will! Thank you

Comment: Yeah still not getting why you had to wrap the ternary ;)

Comment: @RizaKhan, try without.